# Accessing two different arrays within $.ajax() function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got these two pages. One echoes a JSON encoded array and the other uses the JQuery $.ajax syntax to access it. The code looks something like this:

Page 1

```
$array = blah blah
echo json_encode($array);
```

Page 2

```
function load(){
  $.ajax({                                      
    url: 'json_array_file.php',                                                                   
    data: 'value=<?php echo $_GET["session"]; ?>',       
    dataType: 'json',                                                                       
    success: function(data) {                                                       
        var idCurrent = data[0];                                                    
        var idVideo = data[1];
        var idSession = data[2];
        var state = data[4];
        //do stuff with variables
    }
  });
}
```

So the trouble I'm having is that I now need to access two arrays from the first page but I'm not sure what the syntax is to access that second array within the $.ajax function on the second page. Anyone know how?

Comment: Just make page 1 echo an array of arrays containing both arrays. Then the `data` variable in page 2 will contain the same array of arrays.

Comment: Yeah, true, I thought about that but wasn't sure if it was the appropriate way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the PHP side:

```
<?php
   $arr1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
   $arr2 = array(5, 6, 7, 8);

   echo json_encode(array('arr1' => $arr1, 'arr2' => $arr2));
?>
```

On the jQuery side:

```
/* ... stuff ... */
success: function(data) {
    var fromArray1 = data.arr1[0];
    var fromArray2 = data.arr2[0];
    /* etc. */
}
/* ... other stuff ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe returning an multidimensional array helps.